# "I go there always" vs "I go there every day"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, adverbs

> 1. I go there always.
> 2. I go there every day.

Do these sentences have the same meaning by using adverbs ALWAYS and EVERY DAY?
If not, what is the difference?  I am not able to differentiate between these sentences, could you please explain.

Comment: "Do these sentences have the same meaning?"  No.

Answer (score 4):

'Always' depends on the context.

> I always go to bed at ten o'clock.

is the same as

> I go to bed at ten o'clock every day.

But sometimes always means something different from every day.

> I always go to church on Sundays.

means I don't go to church every day, but I do go every Sunday.

> I always have toast with boiled eggs.

means every time I have boiled eggs I also have toast, but I might not have eggs every day

> I always say "hello" to Mrs Smith

means every time I see Mrs Smith I say hello to her. Maybe I see her very often or maybe only a few times a year.

"I go there always" could mean "I go there every day" but it could mean "I go there every week" or "I go there every time something happens"  It depends on the context.